# Null Pointer Exception on FragmentPagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem()

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a `FragmentPagerAdapter` where I override its `setPrimaryItem()`:

```
@Override
public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position,
        Object object) {
    super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);

    ...
}
```

The NPE is occurring inside the `super()`. Here is the code from the support library:

```
@Override
public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment)object;
    if (fragment != mCurrentPrimaryItem) {
        if (mCurrentPrimaryItem != null) {
            mCurrentPrimaryItem.setMenuVisibility(false);
            mCurrentPrimaryItem.setUserVisibleHint(false);
        }
        if (fragment != null) {
            fragment.setMenuVisibility(true);
            fragment.setUserVisibleHint(true);
        }
        mCurrentPrimaryItem = fragment;
    }
}
```

In the cases where the exception occurs, `fragment` is not null so the method `setUserVisibleHint(true)` gets called. This method is as follows:

```
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    if (!mUserVisibleHint && isVisibleToUser && mState < STARTED) {
        mFragmentManager.performPendingDeferredStart(this);
    }
    mUserVisibleHint = isVisibleToUser;
    mDeferStart = !isVisibleToUser;
}
```

This code gets inside the `if` but `mFragmentManager` is null and the NPE occurs. This is not happening on the phones I'm testing but I'm getting bug reports with the problem. I'm instantiating my fragments using a `newInstance()` method where I just call `new Fragment()` and set the arguments in a `Bundle()`.

I noticed in the `Fragment` source code that `mFragmentManager` is null until   `instantiate(FragmentActivity activity, Fragment parent)` is called but I can't call this method directly, it seems, as my fragments are not yet attached to the activity.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this issue by any chance ?

Comment: Not really. :(
I had to add try..catch blocks in different places to ignore the problem for now. It seems related to not properly destroying/recreating fragments so nothing seems to be getting lost.